# Running app from the SDK to a nexus 4 phone produces ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host error

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-touch, connection, nexus-4, sdk

I have before successfully run apps on this device from the SDK.
Now the SDK is giving me an error:

```
[10:27:08] Started /usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/qtc_device_run_app
[10:27:09] ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
[10:27:09] /usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/qtc_device_run_app finished with code 255
```

I have bootstrapped the latest devel-proposed (302) and I've tried the command:

```
adb shell setprop persist.service.ssh true && adb reboot
```

with no luck.

The device works just fine, and I can ssh into from command line no problem, It's only an issue with running an app from the SDK to the device. The device is also detected by the SDK and running in developer mode in the SDK.

Anyone seen this error before or have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent changes made to the Ubuntu SDK have eliminated this problem for me.